# How to fix Facebook likes count in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, facebook, https, facebook-like

I changed the [site](https://paulamusique.com) to HTTPS using the SSL Really Simple plugin on WordPress. However, the likes count is only looking for HTTPS, disregarding HTTP likes.
I debugged on Facebook the URL of a post, and could see that the canonical URL is HTTPS: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fpaulamusique.com%2Fcampanha-valorizacao-da-musica-coral%2F

I already put it in the head of the site:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://paulamusique.com/campanha-valorizacao-da-musica-coral/">
<link rel="canonical" href="http://paulamusique.com/campanha-valorizacao-da-musica-coral/">
```

But it is not working.

I checked on http://sharedcount.com that the likes of HTTP are still right.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: Checking the source code for both `https://paulamusique.com/` and `https://paulamusique.com/campanha-valorizacao-da-musica-coral/` in my browser, the canonical URL _is_ the HTTPS version in both cases. And so is `og:url`.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your plugin is updated, if it is. Try finding the better one.